# Angular Router Animations - error with compiling - Function calls are not supported in decorators

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

I have a small project and I wanted to implement angular animations for the routing but I have an error when compiling (ng build --prod) here are all the codes where I affect this:
-App component

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirestoreService } from './services/firestore.service';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { slider } from './route-animations';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 animations: [ slider ],
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
 constructor(public _af: FirestoreService) {}
 prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
  return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
 }
}
```

route animations:

```js
import { trigger, transition, style, query, group, animateChild, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';

// Basic

export const fader = trigger('routeAnimations', [
 transition('* <=> *', [
  query(
   ':enter, :leave',
   [
    style({
     position: 'absolute',
     left: 0,
     width: '100%',
     opacity: 0,
     transform: 'scale(0) translateY(100%)'
    })
   ],
   { optional: true }
  ),
  query(':enter', [ animate('600ms ease', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'scale(1) translateY(0)' })) ], {
   optional: true
  })
 ])
]);

// Positioned

export const slider = trigger('routeAnimations', [
 transition('* => isLeft', slideTo('left')),
 transition('* => isRight', slideTo('right')),
 transition('isRight => *', slideTo('left')),
 transition('isLeft => *', slideTo('right'))
]);

export const transformer = trigger('routeAnimations', [
 transition('* => isLeft', translateTo({ x: -100, y: -100, rotate: -720 })),
 transition('* => isRight', translateTo({ x: 100, y: -100, rotate: 90 })),
 transition('isRight => *', translateTo({ x: -100, y: -100, rotate: 360 })),
 transition('isLeft => *', translateTo({ x: 100, y: -100, rotate: -360 }))
]);
function slideTo(direction) {
 const optional = { optional: true };
 return [
  query(
   ':enter, :leave',
   [
    style({
     position: 'absolute',
     top: 0,
     [direction]: 0,
     width: '100%'
    })
   ],
   optional
  ),
  query(':enter', [ style({ [direction]: '-100%' }) ]),
  group([
   query(':leave', [ animate('600ms ease', style({ [direction]: '100%' })) ], optional),
   query(':enter', [ animate('600ms ease', style({ [direction]: '0%' })) ])
  ])
  // Normalize the page style... Might not be necessary

  // Required only if you have child animations on the page
  // query(':leave', animateChild()),
  // query(':enter', animateChild()),
 ];
}

export function translateTo({ x = 100, y = 0, rotate = 0 }) {
 const optional = { optional: true };
 return [
  query(
   ':enter, :leave',
   [
    style({
     position: 'absolute',
     top: 0,
     left: 0,
     width: '100%'
    })
   ],
   optional
  ),
  query(':enter', [ style({ transform: `translate(${x}%, ${y}%) rotate(${rotate}deg)` }) ]),
  group([
   query(
    ':leave',
    [ animate('600ms ease-out', style({ transform: `translate(${x}%, ${y}%) rotate(${rotate}deg)` })) ],
    optional
   ),
   query(':enter', [ animate('600ms ease-out', style({ transform: `translate(0, 0) rotate(0)` })) ])
  ])
 ];
}

// Keyframes

export const stepper = trigger('routeAnimations', [
 transition('* <=> *', [
  query(':enter, :leave', [
   style({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    width: '100%'
   })
  ]),
  group([
   query(':enter', [
    animate(
     '2000ms ease',
     keyframes([
      style({ transform: 'scale(0) translateX(100%)', offset: 0 }),
      style({ transform: 'scale(0.5) translateX(25%)', offset: 0.3 }),
      style({ transform: 'scale(1) translateX(0%)', offset: 1 })
     ])
    )
   ]),
   query(':leave', [
    animate(
     '2000ms ease',
     keyframes([
      style({ transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 0 }),
      style({ transform: 'scale(0.5) translateX(-25%) rotate(0)', offset: 0.35 }),
      style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-50%) rotate(-180deg) scale(6)', offset: 1 })
     ])
    )
   ])
  ])
 ])
]);
```

the error is:
ERROR in src\app\app.component.ts(8,16): Error during template compile of 'AppComponent'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'slideTo' was called in 'slider'
    'slider' calls 'slideTo'.

Comment: This is a pretty good article that explains exactly why the JIT compiler works but the AOT compiler does not. https://blog.angularindepth.com/total-guide-to-dynamic-angular-animations-that-can-be-toggled-at-runtime-be5bb6778a0a

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that when building in an Angular app AOT, it takes the specified component metadata and pre-compiles the component factory. Now the angular compiler only understands a subset of javascript. You will have to rewrite your code considering [this](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#metadata-restrictions).

In short: `slideTo` can't be used because it declares `const optional = { optional: true };` before returning. You should just inline the `optional` object where necessary. I'm not sure about the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

create three variables:

```
optional
toTheLeft
toTheRight
```

assign these variables instead of the

```
slideTo('left')
slideTo('right')
```

functions

full code:

```js
const optional = { optional: true };
let toTheRight = [
  query(':enter, :leave', [
    style({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0',
      right: 0,
      width: '100%',
    })
  ], optional),
  query(':enter', [
    style({ right: '-100%',  })
  ]),
  group([
    query(':leave', [
      animate('300ms ease', style({ right: '100%', }))
    ], optional),
    query(':enter', [
      animate('300ms ease', style({ right: '0%'}))
    ])
  ]),
];
let toTheLeft = [
  query(':enter, :leave', [
    style({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0',
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
    })
  ], optional),
  query(':enter', [
    style({ right: '-100%',  })
  ]),
  group([
    query(':leave', [
      animate('300ms ease', style({ left: '100%', }))
    ], optional),
    query(':enter', [
      animate('300ms ease', style({ left: '0%'}))
    ])
  ]),
]
 
 
export const slider =
  trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* => isLeft', toTheLeft),
    transition('* => isRight', toTheRight),
    transition('isRight => *', toTheLeft),
    transition('isLeft => *', toTheRight),
  ]);
```